# how to use between in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID          NAME                     TIME
---------------------------------------------
1   United Arab Emirates    3:00
2   Sri Lanka                     2:00
3   Turkey                    4:00
4   Yemen                     4:00
5   Us                    11:00
6   Sweden                    5:00
7   England                   6:00
8   Singapore           23:00
```

Dear I want list of name between **2.00** to **10.00** time which is varchar field.
i did

```
select * from tblindiantime where IndianTime  between ('1.00') and ('10.00')
```

which gives me wrong records..
in other cases it shows me conversion erros..
plz help

Comment: Some research into duplicate questions / answers would have helped you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948133/use-between-with-varchar-sql-server

Comment: What is the data type of Time column? where is the IndianTime column?

Comment: @prakash: Time is varchar (is in original question). IndianTime is probably a variable (amit patil has asked multiple questions which suggest this). Dave's answer should work (and is the better idea in general).

Comment: Seems you have done lot of research on "amitpatil200" :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify '1.00' and 10.00' as datetimes, assuming the IndianTime column  is a datetime.

Answer (score 2):

What data type is your time stored as? *CHAR? If your RDBMS is MSSQL and you are using the SQL 2008 [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) datatype, this should work

```
select * from tblindiantime  where IndianTime between '01:00' and '10:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
... where convert(int, substring(IndianTime, 0, charindex('.', IndianTime))
```

This might be off by 1 in either way, but you get an idea.