# BETWEEN and LIKE on VarChar Field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that has the follow `WHERE` criteria condition:

```
or ((code between 'T71.112' and 'T72') and code like 'T__.__2%')
```

I was unaware that this could be a valid SQL statement and would think that it would require substringing and recasting parts of the field to handle the `BETWEEN`.

Is this something unique to SQL Server's implementation and in fact valid?

EDIT:

It sounds like this is valid under most situations/systems one would ever expect to encounter.  How numbers are evaluated in Varchar for the BETWEEN was my primary concern, but it seems to produce expected results.  I have done some testing which seems to confirm it as well.

Comment: The above is standard SQL.

Comment: It's standard, and would work on most mainstream DBMS's --> MsSQL, MySQL, Oracle .. etc etc

Comment: What bit are you concerned about? There will be an alphabetic range `BETWEEN` the values of two strings. "Bear" is `BETWEEN` "Aardvark" and "Christmas", say. Some niceties may depend on your locale settings, character encoding and collation, and vary between systems, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: on most systems the results *could* change based on the collation you are using.  Should be fine for Latin based collations.

Comment: Number evaluation in varchar can be screwy...Varchar numbers won't order as 1,2,3,8,10,14,16 like integers will, instead it evaluates by the first char, then the second.  Like this : 1,11,14,15,100,2,20,26,3,34.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use 'between' with varchar (sql server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948133/use-between-with-varchar-sql-server)