# Compare datetime in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a sql 2008 database and I am creating a stored procedure that shall check if a datetime is more than 3 hours old but I don't know how to do it.

Do you have some way to do it?

the datetime is a field in the table.

BR

Comment: the answer my friend, is blowing in SO, the answer is blowing in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807909/how-can-i-compare-time-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than applying `DATEDIFF` to the column value, which will negate an index, I suggest using a comparison of the column to an expression (which *can* use an index).

If you want this as a filter:

```
SELECT columns
FROM dbo.table
WHERE DateTimeColumn < DATEADD(HOUR, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

(If you want only the rows that are *newer* than 3 hours old, change `<` to `>` or `>=`.)

If you want to return all rows with a column showing whether it is more than 3 hours old:

```
SELECT columns, [3HoursOld] = CASE
    WHEN DateTimeColumn < DATEADD(HOUR, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    THEN 'Yes, older than 3 hours.'
    ELSE 'No, not older than 3 hours.'
END
FROM dbo.table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at the [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

You would then use with datepart set to `hh` and the enddate set to the current time. To get the current database time you could use `GETDATE()`. Compare the result with `3` since it will  return the number of hours passed.

Answer (score 1):

@date is the date you want to compare

```
declare @date datetime

set @date= '2012-02-15 14:20:42.797' 

SELECT DateDiff(hh, DATEADD(hh,-3,@date), GETDATE()) --if it's > 3
```

you better create a Boolean function that does the trick that you can use where ever you like