# How to compare time in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two  columns in table as in a string format `starttime` and `endtime` in `(HH:MM tt)` format like
`Starttime = 12:15PM` and `endtime = 12:52PM`
I want's to add condition in where clause for sql query to check if startime is greater than endtime

Like below.

```
Select * from table where StartTime > EndTime
```

(I am not able to compare this condition here)

Can any one help me to add write where for comparing time.

Note: Both the values are stored in string format.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`? Their syntaxes pretty much differ.

Comment: You should add the full date as starttime and endtime, in some cases start time might be 23:55 and end time will be 00:15. If you include the dates you can use datediff to get the proper result.

Comment: @WernerWaage what if start/end time is a recurring event.

Comment: @Magnus Sorry! I made an assumption instead of a suggestion :)

Comment: Please check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807909/how-can-i-compare-time-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string values to timestamp or date time format and then use your where condition.

--Edited

For SQL Server,

```
Select * from table where CONVERT(datetime, StartTime , 120) > CONVERT(datetime, EndTime , 120)
```

Comment: +1 if you show the actual solution instead of explaining it.  You're right, but he might not understand how to do it (as well as for future reference).

Comment: I am not sure of DB he uses. This can be considered, CONVERT(datetime, String_to_b_converted, 120)

Comment: I am using sql server 2005

Comment: Then you can use convert() itself. You use this condition in where,

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `string` values to `Time` before you do the comparison:

```
Select * from table where CAST(StartTime As Time) > CAST(EndTime As Time)
```

The best solution however is to change the data type of the `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns to data type `Time` rather than `string`

Comment: I tried that but it shows below error Type TIME is not a defined system type.

Comment: @Irshad For using `TIME` you need 2008 or above. But using `DateTime` should work for your case also. The date will be 1900-01-01, but that does not matter since you only care about the time part.

Comment: I am getting this error when i used datetime Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string. even when I fire this query it gives me select  Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),starttime,100) as DateTime)  from table  it gives me error like this  Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONVERT (TIME, StartTime) > CONVERT (TIME, EndTime)
```

For SQL 2005:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONVERT(Varchar(8), CONVERT(DATETIME, StartTime), 8) > CONVERT(Varchar(8), CONVERT(DATETIME, EndTime), 8)
```

Comment: Actually I am using sql server 2005 so not able to use TIME. TIME will work in sql server 2008 and above versions of that sql server

Comment: Could you try this: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CONVERT(Varchar(8), Convert(DATETIME, StartTime), 8) > CONVERT(Varchar(8), Convert(DATETIME, EndTime), 8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from table where CAST(starttime AS TIME) > CAST(endtime AS TIME)
```

or

try this

```
 Select * from table where CAST( '2013/01/01 ' + starttime AS DATETIME) > CAST( '2013/01/01 ' + Endtime AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I am getting this error when i used datetime Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: even when I fire this query it gives me select  Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),starttime,100) as DateTime)  from table  it gives me error like this  Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `CAST` it to `TIME`

```
Select * from tbl where CAST(StartTime as TIME) > CAST(EndTime as TIME)
```

### [Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cb04/3)