# Compare two time strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have a string variable that denotes a time:

```
@time = '5:00 PM'
```

I need to check if the current time `getdate()` is after or before `@time`.  How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Side note; if you need good performance, you're storing it wrong.

Comment: comparing two times in sql requires a float conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807909/how-can-i-compare-time-in-sql-server

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I agree, but unfortunately I'm dealing with dependent code that I can't change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

SQL 2008+

```
if datediff(ss,cast(@time as time),cast(GetDate() as time)) < 0
   print 'Future'
else
   print 'Past'
```

Earlier:

```
if DatePart(hh,GETDATE())*60+DATEPART(mm,getDate()) < DatePart(hh,@time)*60+DATEPART(mm,@time)   
   print 'Future' 
else   
   Print 'Past'
```

Comment: You do need to add a statement to execute when the comparison succeeds or fails.

Comment: So this will return true if getdate's time is earlier than @time? Thx

Comment: If the second parameter is before the third, you'll get a positive result. If the second parameter is later than the third, it'll be a negative. So, if your @time is after GetDate(), the datediff() value will be negative.

Comment: I'm getting an error: Type time is not a defined system type.  I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Time is actually a 2008+ datatype. I've combined my answer with Sparky's for the comparison on earlier versions.

Answer (score 3):

One way, but not great on performance.

```
declare @time varchar(20)
set @time = '5:00pm'
select DatePart(hh,GETDATE())*60+DATEPART(mm,getDate()) as CurTime,
       DatePart(hh,@time)*60+DATEPART(mm,@time) as TheTime
```

Comment: Good solution for earlier server versions.

Answer (score 0):

--@timeToCompare  here,Replace your string

```
Declare @timeToCompare time =CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(time,'17:30:00'), 114);
Declare @Currenttime time= CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(time,GETDATE()), 114);
```

--Compare

```
if @timeToCompare > @Currenttime
 print 0
else
 print -1
```

You can also use case when condition.