# Use Converted Date Time column to filter if one is greater

Tags: sql-server

I am selecting two

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE.EMP_EMPNO,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), PAYHIST.PH_DATE,101) AS DATE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), PAYHIST.PH_LASTCLOCK,108) AS Time,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), SHIFT.SFT_END,108) AS Time
```

Converted the two columns to just show `Time`, only want it to display if `Payhist.PH_Lastclock < Shift.Shift_End` but cannot get my where clause to read the converted columns values.

If the columns are not converted they display as below:

[image: early Out Report]

Comment: Can you add your where clause to the example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting the fields in your where clause to `VARCHAR`, you will need to convert them back to `DATETIME` fields as well.

Try this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), PAYHIST.PH_LASTCLOCK,108)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), SHIFT.SFT_END,108))
```

Answer (score 0):

this link will help you, better understanding of time comparison.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/808507/979011